# C# Check if a program is in fullscreen

Tags: c#, .net

I Would like to know how to check if a process is in fullscreen or not

Thanks

Comment: Is this the process running your application or some other random process that might be running?

Comment: other random process got with Process.GetProcesses();

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use P/Invoke to get access to that kind of information about another process. This code should get you on the right track:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp13
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static WINDOWPLACEMENT GetPlacement(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
            placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(placement);
            GetWindowPlacement(hwnd, ref placement);
            return placement;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach(Process p in procs)
            {
                if(p.ProcessName == "notepad")
                {
                    var state = GetPlacement(p.MainWindowHandle);
                    MessageBox.Show(state.showCmd.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public int length;
        public int flags;
        public ShowWindowCommands showCmd;
        public Point ptMinPosition;
        public Point ptMaxPosition;
        public Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
    }

    internal enum ShowWindowCommands : int
    {
        Hide = 0,
        Normal = 1,
        Minimized = 2,
        Maximized = 3,
    }
}
```